# How to fix collection View refresh error in swift 4

Tags: swift

I'm getting an error while trying to refresh my collectionView which is strange because it was working perfect last I ran the app. The error is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

```
func setupRefreshControl() {

    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
    collectionView?.refreshControl = refreshControl
}

@objc func handleUpdateFeed() {
    handleRefresh()
}

fileprivate func fetchallPosts() {
    fetchPostUserIds()
    fetchPosts()
}

@objc func handleRefresh() {
    print("Handling refresh..")
    posts.removeAll()
    fetchPostUserIds()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add more details about your situation to help people answer you? What debugging have you done to locate the source of the range error? How long has it been since the app last worked? What has changed in your computing environment since the app last worked? More details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try Collection view reload in side the function.

```
self.collectionview.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

Main problem was refreshing collection view. Hence you can try one of below method :

```
@objc func handleRefresh() 
{
  print("Handling refresh..")
  posts.removeAll()
  fetchPostUserIds()
  collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

OR

You can use `collectionView.reloadData()` in `fetchPostUserIds()` after getting response.